# jQuery form submit not working rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Got the following error when submitting a form through jquery in rails 4.

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

the issue occur because of jquery form submit not working.after refreshing the page particular record added in table.
also got the input from stack-overflow gem "jquery-turbolinks" may casue the problem.

after this gem also same error coming.
any help on this?

note: Currently upgrading the application from rails 3 to rails 4.

ref: [JQuery gets loaded only on page refresh in Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application)

Comment: can u show how u r submitting the form via jquery.

Comment: not only in single place.in whole application wherever we used jqery bind,unbind its not working.in the sense its working but responding 406 response means when i refresh particular functionality working.

Comment: yes.I have some problems with iframe and respond_to_parent  and i resolved now.