# Masonry-rails works on first load, but if I click my navbar-brand to go back to index, the masonry animations do not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, jquery-masonry, masonry

Currently working on a project on my local machine to learn RoR.  When I navigate to localhost:3000, the page looks great.  The masonry animations work just fine.

However, if at any point I click my navbar-brand to go back to localhost:3000, the masonry does not work.  However, if I refresh the page, the masonry returns.

I tried a few different things, but each has been giving me other errors..

Here is how my html, head, and body in `application.html.haml` are set up (the right way, I think):

```
!!! 5
%html
    %head
        %title My App
        = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
        = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => true 
        = csrf_meta_tags
        %body
            %nav.navbar.navbar-default
                .container
                    .navbar-brand= link_to "My App", root_path
```

If I purposefully set the %head indentation back so it is just under %head:

```
!!! 5
%html
%head
    %title My App
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => true 
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %body
        %nav.navbar.navbar-default
            .container
                .navbar-brand= link_to "My App", root_path
```

then the issue where masonry does not apply on redirect back to index is gone.  However, another issue then presents itself.  I have a confirm for my delete, so with this setup the confirm box does not go away even after I click OK.  That happens in my show.html.haml here:

```
= link_to "Remove", shape_path, method: :delete, 
  data: { confirm: "Click OK to remove" }
```

I am really lost and would appreciate some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When you click in a navbar link the page is not reloaded.
I solve this problem using the gem jquery-turbolink

add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

then run in your terminal

```
bundle install
```

and add this to your application.js

```
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

I found the solution here:

[JQuery gets loaded only on page refresh in Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application)