# Bxslider only works when refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bxslider

Why does bxslider not loading in the beginning but works when I refresh the page?
I already begin with `$(document).ready(function(){});`

I'm building it on Rails FYI.

[https://photos4humanity.herokuapp.com/galleries](https://photos4humanity.herokuapp.com/galleries/1)
If you click on gallery, you will see a black page, then if you refresh it appears. Also it is not showing when I just click onto the link from the nav bar.
It should look like this
[image]

Comment: It's working for me in Firefox. Could it be a Chrome problem?

Comment: nope it's still not working. When you click onto the link from the nav bar, or access it from the photo, it does not work. I just tried with Safari

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some troubleshooting, it's a rails specific situation. Turbolink that came with Rails prevented the site to reload. So download the jquery-turbolink gem will work.

[JQuery gets loaded only on page refresh in Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application)