# IE11 wierd behaviour -- JavaScript works only after reloading a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a website prototype https://arcane-beyond-35849.herokuapp.com/
I have a strange bug. In internet explorer v11.
please go to the site and press new button.
You will see this picture...

[image: Initial View]

Then you can reload the page and see this...

[image: View After Reload]

I use the [jQuery steps wizard](http://www.jquery-steps.com/).

So I have no idea why the first time everything breaks.
*(If you need a code I can provide it just tell me.)*

```
$(".myform").steps({
    *some stuff and options
});
```

Okay I found another weird behavior when you go to the main page and try to click on the menu button in the right top corner nothing happens.
When you reload a page and click menu button again side menu appears.

[image: A View of More Woe]

I  simply on document.ready use something like this :

```
$('.somebutton').click(function(){});
```

I guess I should provide code and I will do it as soon as get to another laptop. But if take away all business logic The code is as simple as I described.

In google chrome everything works normal.
Can someone help? Seems like my JavaScript code just doesn't execute.

**Update:**
okay  guys Console give me some errors. My IE11 not in English so no point to post exact errors here.
There is something about the content that is loaded over http when I have https.
But it's just a placeholder picture. So I don't know. And when I reload page my JavaScript code works. So this is strange.

Comment: Is this a rails app? It seems like a turbolinks issue

Comment: I'm not sure. But it smells like the DOM elements that you're trying to manipulate aren't ready. I don't have IE11 here to test it. But try console.log the elements before you call your plugin and check if the elements really exist.

Comment: it's a common issue, try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application

Comment: I will tell you tomorrow as soon as i get to the laptop if it helped. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks man removing turbolinks worked))) that's cool. I upvoted your comments, you can post it as an answer if you want and  I will accept it)