# Initialize Bootstrap-File-Input on Rails + Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have 2 routes an index and an edit route. On the edit route i have an input to initialize as a bootstrap-file input.
If i refresh my page on the edit route, the bootstrap-file input is initialized, but if i come from the index page through a link to the edit route, it is not being initialized, how do i do this?

[This is the edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeHT2.png)

[This is the edit page if coming from the index route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7ofq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question, the user explains it very well.

[JQuery gets loaded only on page refresh in Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application)

To fix what rails is doing. Add gem 'jquery-turbolinks' to your gem file and follow the instructions provided on https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks