# Rails Coffescript Not Executing Until Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app that is using Turbolinks (v2.1.0), jquery-rails(4.2.1), bootstrap-sass (v3.2.0.0), and rails_script (v2.0.3) to arrange my Coffescript. Problem is that I cannot get my CoffeScript to execute unless I do a page re-load. My application.js file reads:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require rails_script
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I read somewhere ([JQuery gets loaded only on page refresh in Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application)) that by requiring "jquery.turbolinks" before "turbolinks" it would execute as expected, but no luck.

My CoffeScript is the following:

```
class App.Rating extends App.Base

beforeAction: (action) =>
  return

afterAction: (action) =>
  return

index: =>
  alert 'in'
  #hide the new rating button if we are looking at specific ratings
  $('[id^=outer]').on 'show.bs.collapse', ->

    $('.new_rating').fadeOut 100
    return
```

The alert and code does not run unless I refresh the page. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Turbolink might be the root cause

Comment: Try removing turbolink

Comment: Is this in a coffeescript file? What is the full code that you have in there?

Comment: Won't I lose efficiencies if I remove Turbolinks?

Comment: BigJ - added full contents of the CoffeScript file. The code executes as expected once I hit refresh, so don't believe there is an error in there.

Comment: Coffeescript isn't my strong suit, I'd suggest: '$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->'

Comment: I ended up ditching Turbolinks all together. Too many issues. I will have to live with potential performance issues down the road. Thanks to all for feedback!